# Why does the rule about the maximum versions of the dependencies also apply to go directives less than 1.21?

Tags: go

[Documentation for **the go directive**](https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-file-go) in the go.mod file of the main module states the following:

> At go 1.21 or higher:
> - ...
> - The go line must be greater than or equal to the go line of all dependencies.
> - ...

Therefore, based on that, it follows that if the go directive in the go.mod file of the main module is smaller than the go directive of any imported (directly/indirectly) module by the main module, the build will fail. What is emphasized here is that **this rule only applies if the go directive in the go.mod file of the main module is greater than or equal to `go 1.21.0`.** Therefore, if the go directive in the go.mod file of the main module is set to `go 1.21.0`, and some module it includes in its go.mod file has `go 1.22.0`, the build will fail. This is all clear to me.

What confuses me is that this rule for some reason also applies if the go directive in go.mod file of the main module is set to a version smaller than 1.21.0, for example, `go 1.20.0`. This is contrary to what is stated in the documentation.

For example, take a look at the following [example module](https://github.com/leabit/moduleA) (I made it just for demonstration purposes). It has the go directive set to `go 1.22.0`.

If you import that module from the main module with the go directive set to `go 1.22.0`, everything works as it should. On the other hand, if the go directive in the main module is set to `go 1.21.0`, build won't work. This is also expected, since it breaks the requirement. What is strange is that if you set the go directive in the main module to `go 1.20.0` or something lower, it still does not work and, according to documentation, it should since the above rule does not apply to go directive lower than `go 1.21.0`.

What's happening here?

Btw, I am using Go toolchain 1.22.